# Quiz not working properly, after clicking the submit button, nothing happens

Tags: javascript, html

I made a quiz, I used a code that was online and formatted it a bit. 
So when you click on submit there should be an answer like u need to do more
studying or something and a score.

```html
<div id="main">

<!-- open main div -->
<div class="quizstyle">
<h1>Quiz</h1>
<form id="form1" action=" ">
<h3>Question 1</h3>
<div class="row"><input name="variable" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 1</div>
<div class="row"><input name="variable" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 2</div>
<div class="row"><input name="variable" type="radio" value="33" />Answer 3</div>
&nbsp;
<h3>Question 2</h3>
<div class="row"><input name="sub" type="radio" />Answer 1</div>
<div class="row"><input name="sub" type="radio" />Answer 2</div>
<div class="row"><input name="sub" type="radio" />Answer 3</div>
&nbsp;
<h3>Question 3</h3>
<div class="row"><input name="con" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 1</div>
<div class="row"><input name="con" type="radio" value="33" />Answer 2</div>
<div class="row"><input name="con" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 3</div>
</form></div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

Your grade is: <span id="grade">__</span>
<p id="grade2"></p>

</div>
<!-- close main div -->

<script>
document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit=function() {
       variable = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "variable"]:checked').value);
    sub = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "sub"]:checked').value);
    con = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "con"]:checked').value);
    
    result = variable + sub + con;
    
 document.getElementById("grade").innerHTML = result;
    
if (result == 0) {result2 = "I don't think you studied."};
if (result == 33) {result2 = "You need to spend more time. Try again."};
if (result == 66) {result2 = "I think you could do better. Try again."};
if (result == 99) {result2 = "Excellent!"};
document.getElementById("grade2").innerHTML = result2; 

return false; // required to not refresh the page; just leave this here
} //this ends the submit function

</script>
```

Does anyone know what the problem may be ?

Comment: We need to see your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically forgot to include submit button inside the form and also forgot to give values to 2nd question's radio inputs. Also initialization of result2 variable

here is working code

```html
<div id="main">

<!-- open main div -->
<div class="quizstyle">
<h1>Quiz</h1>
<form id="form1" action=" ">
<h3>Question 1</h3>
<div class="row"><input name="variable" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 1</div>
<div class="row"><input name="variable" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 2</div>
<div class="row"><input name="variable" type="radio" value="33" />Answer 3</div>
&nbsp;
<h3>Question 2</h3>
<div class="row"><input name="sub" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 1</div>
<div class="row"><input name="sub" type="radio"  value="34" />Answer 2</div>
<div class="row"><input name="sub" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 3</div>
&nbsp;
<h3>Question 3</h3>
<div class="row"><input name="con" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 1</div>
<div class="row"><input name="con" type="radio" value="33" />Answer 2</div>
<div class="row"><input name="con" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 3</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</div>


Your grade is: <span id="grade">__</span>
<p id="grade2"></p>

</div>
<!-- close main div -->

<script>
document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit=function() {
       variable = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "variable"]:checked').value);
    sub = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "sub"]:checked').value);
    con = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "con"]:checked').value);
    
    result = variable + sub + con;
    
 document.getElementById("grade").innerHTML = result;
 var result2 = ""
    

if (result == 0) {result2 = "I don't think you studied."};
if (result == 33) {result2 = "You need to spend more time. Try again."};
if (result == 66) {result2 = "I think you could do better. Try again."};
if (result == 99) {result2 = "Excellent!"};
document.getElementById("grade2").innerHTML = result2; 

return false; // required to not refresh the page; just leave this here
} //this ends the submit function

</script>
```

Comment: @JamesDouglas  agree but mentioned it to follow best practices.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your submit `<input type="submit>` within your form, you didn't initialize your `var result2`, and you didn't have a `value` set for your second question so it was reading `NaN`

```html
<div id="main">

  <!-- open main div -->
  <div class="quizstyle">
    <h1>Quiz</h1>
    <form id="form1" action=" ">
      <h3>Question 1</h3>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="variable" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 1</div>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="variable" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 2</div>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="variable" type="radio" value="33" />Answer 3</div>
      &nbsp;
      <h3>Question 2</h3>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="sub" type="radio" value="33" />Answer 1</div>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="sub" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 2</div>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="sub" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 3</div>
      &nbsp;
      <h3>Question 3</h3>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="con" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 1</div>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="con" type="radio" value="33" />Answer 2</div>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="con" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 3</div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </div>


  Your grade is: <span id="grade">__</span>
  <p id="grade2"></p>

</div>
<!-- close main div -->

<script>
  document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit = function() {
      variable = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "variable"]:checked').value);
      sub = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "sub"]:checked').value);
      con = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "con"]:checked').value);

      result = variable + sub + con;

      document.getElementById("grade").innerHTML = result;
      var result2 = "";
      if (result == 0) {
        result2 = "I don't think you studied."
      };
      if (result == 33) {
        result2 = "You need to spend more time. Try again."
      };
      if (result == 66) {
        result2 = "I think you could do better. Try again."
      };
      if (result == 99) {
        result2 = "Excellent!"
      };
      document.getElementById("grade2").innerHTML = result2;

      return false; // required to not refresh the page; just leave this here
    } //this ends the submit function
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The form isn't being submitted, because the submit button needs to be *inside* the form. You also have some errors - like missing semicolons - and you've forgotten to add values for the second batch of answers.

See snippet.

```html
<div id="main">

<!-- open main div -->
<div class="quizstyle">
<h1>Quiz</h1>
<form id="form1" action=" ">
<h3>Question 1</h3>
<div class="row"><input name="variable" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 1</div>
<div class="row"><input name="variable" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 2</div>
<div class="row"><input name="variable" type="radio" value="33" />Answer 3</div>
&nbsp;
<h3>Question 2</h3>
<div class="row"><input name="sub" type="radio" value="33" />Answer 1</div>
<div class="row"><input name="sub" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 2</div>
<div class="row"><input name="sub" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 3</div>
&nbsp;
<h3>Question 3</h3>
<div class="row"><input name="con" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 1</div>
<div class="row"><input name="con" type="radio" value="33" />Answer 2</div>
<div class="row"><input name="con" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 3</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form></div>

Your grade is: <span id="grade">__</span>
<p id="grade2"></p>

</div>
<!-- close main div -->

<script>
document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit = function() {
  variable = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "variable"]:checked').value);
  sub = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "sub"]:checked').value);
  con = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "con"]:checked').value);
  result = variable + sub + con;
  document.getElementById("grade").innerHTML = result;
  if (result === 0) {
    result2 = "I don't think you studied.";
  }
  if (result === 33) {
    result2 = "You need to spend more time. Try again.";
  }
  if (result === 66) {
    result2 = "I think you could do better. Try again.";
  }
  if (result === 99) {
    result2 = "Excellent!";
  }
  document.getElementById("grade2").innerHTML = result2;
  return false; // required to not refresh the page; just leave this here
};
</script>
```

Comment: It worked and I see where I was wrong, Thank you James !